# Orbital angular momentum of nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

For nuclei, I know that it is the $J^{\pi}$ that is usually measured/calculated, which is the spin-parity. I don't see "orbital angular momentum" of a nucleus very often. Now my notion of spin vs. orbital angular momentum is that spin is entirely instrisic, while orbital angular momentum is more of a classical characteristic (by movement/orbit in a bit more of a literal sense).

Do nuclei even have orbital angular momentum? Is their magnetic moment-like properties only derived from its spin-parity, or am I mistaken? What's really throwing me off is that spin is always in half-integer units, whereas orbital angular momentum is 'always' in whole-integer units.

Comment: Couldn't it be that you confuse *orbital angular momentum of the whole nucleus*, with the orbital angular momentum of ***nucleons*** within the shell-model of nucleus?

Comment: That is very possible.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: See Bill N's answer.

Comment: Oh no I mean like how does one determine the orbital angular momentum of an entire nucleus going around, let's say, another entire nucleus?

Comment: That may be in molecules, for example? Orbital movement around the center of mass?

Comment: Molecules do have quantized angular momentum states.  If you're talking about angular momentum of unbound states, that would be what's happening in collision experiments, e.g., heavy ion collisions which produce J>20 hbar states. The angular momentum brought in by the projectile can be large.

Comment: Why has no one mentioned halo nuclei, where a cloud of "valence" neutrons and/or protons orbit a "core nucleus" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a famous example of a nucleus with internal orbital angular momentum, consider the deuteron.  Considerations of exchange symmetry, spin, and isospin demand that the deuteron have unit spin, rather than zero spin.  However the pion-nucleon interaction, gleaned from neutron-proton scattering and deuteron formation, suggests that about 4% of the deuteron wavefunction is $D$-wave, with orbital angular momentum $L=2$. (The $P$-wave component, with $L=1$, would have negative parity, $(-1)^L$; the deuteron's parity is positive.)

Answer (score 5):

The angular momentum of the nucleus is the combined contribution of the spin-orbit angular momenta of the constituent particles. In order for an entity to have orbital angular momentum of its own it must some conceptual orbit: electrons in the atom, protons and neutrons in the nucleus, atoms in a molecule. That's why the angular momentum of a nucleus is generally referred to as spin: there's no definable orbit when talking about a single nucleus.

The success of the nuclear shell model strongly supports that each nucleon has a spin-orbit ($\vec{j}$) angular momentum which it contributes, and like particles combine first. Each $j$ quantum number will be a half-integer, with like $|lj>$ pairs combining (in the energy ground state) to give zero spin contribution. All nuclei with even proton count (Z) and even neutron count (N=A-Z) have $0^+$ spin and parity in the ground state, the protons combining to zero and the neutrons combining to zero. All even-odds and odd-evens (referring to Z and N) have odd-half integer spin with a parity determined by the $l$ of the extra (odd) nucleon.  Odd-odd nuclei have integer, usually non-zero, spin. The two half integer quantum numbers (from the odd proton and the odd neutron) combine for an integer.

Comment: But the user didn't tell you whether he refers to a global orbiting of the nucleus, or to internal dynamics of the nucleus, i.e. of the constituents.

Answer (score 0):

In a Hydrogen atom, the "orbital angular momentum of electron" is in fact the relative orbital angular momentum. The nucleus (proton) turns around the common atomic center too, but in a smaller orbit. The atomic electron and the nucleus do not have certain individual orbital angular momenta. They are in mixed states. See my explanations [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Db4rFq72mLMWE1OGIwNTUtOTdmMC00ZTNlLThiYzktODI3ODVhOGVkNzc5/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/zoom-in-atom-or-unknown-physics-of-short-distances/).

Answer (score -2):

It's made up of many particles. I would assume some of them "orbit" the center. I know many electron orbitals have angular momentum. The orbitals of nuclei are less well-understood, but I would expect the same is true.